How to Set Expiry Dates for Azure Resources and send reminder emails to decommission them
Hello Azure community,
In our infrastructure provisioning workflow, we rely on Terraform for VMs and manual creation for resources like App Gateways. However, we often face challenges in remembering to clean up resources after testing, leading to unnecessary costs and resource clutter.
I'm looking for a solution to set expiry dates for Azure resources, allowing us to specify a date at the time of creation. Once the expiry date is reached, I'd like to trigger email reminders for resource deletion.
Are there any existing tools or methods within Azure that can assist with this functionality? Any insights or recommendations on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!
pretty much a newbie to azure so havent really found any thing

One possibility could be to place an "ExpirationDate" tag on each resource and then create a Logic or Function App with a time-based trigger to poll the tag and drop the associated resources when the date passes.  This can be a little tricky though, as some resources are created implicitly and the tag might not propagate to those.  Placing the tag at the resource group level works around the issue if dropping all resources in he group and the group itself is acceptable.
If you're not already doing it, adding an automatic shutdown schedule to your VM's can help contain costs.
